# Conditional use of a parameter default's value, without reflection

Tags: c#

just out of curiosity, I would like to know if it's possible to conditionally use a default parameter value to call a function or not. It's easier to explain with an example:

```
    private void Function1(string param1)
    {
        // OPTION 1
        // I can do it this way: if param is null or empty, use the Function2 default value
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1))
        {
            Function2();
        }
        else
        {
            Function2(param1);
        }

        // OPTION 2
        // Can I replace above code with this pseudo code?
        // If param is empty, use Function2 default parameter value? In this case, default_param_value = A
        Function2(string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1) ? default_param_value : param1);
    }

    private void Function2(string param2 = "A")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(param2);
    }
```

Without using Reflection, can I call Function2 with a defined value or the default parameter value, not worrying about what's defined in Function2 header (using something like this pseudo keyword default_param_value)? Is there a way to achieve option 2 above?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What reflection you are talking here? I do not see any code that makes use of reflection.

Comment: Use option 1. Don't even bother with option 2 because you just made a mess of things for no reason, even if you can do option 2.

Comment: @sam 1, I'm not using reflection and I'm trying to achieve a solution that also doesn't use.

Comment: You have to use reflection to determine default parameter values - Option 1 is best.

Comment: @Ricardo thanks for confirming. Do you want to use param2 when param1 is null or empty? Please confirm.

Comment: @sam, that's it! Supoose I don't know what's the default value ("A" in this case): I want to use param2 whenever param1 is null or empty.

Comment: @Ricardo when it is empty, then param2 value will not be used. Please see my updated answer

Comment: The question does not make sense.  You've already defined the type of param1 as string.  Thus, you know the default value (i.e. "").  If you want to have the type of param1 be variable, you would have to make the function generic and then you could use default(T) for the default value of the unknown type of the parameter.

Comment: The option 1 looks just fine

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski you are right, option 1 is ok. I just wanted to know if option 2 was possible.

Comment: Ideally, `Function2` should be the place to handle this case: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2)) param2 = "A";`

Comment: Thanks @RufusL . As I said, just wanted to know if it was possible, but probably not. No problem :)

Comment: @JPAlioto, Sorry, but you didn't understood what I'm asking.
It doesn't matter it is a string or anything else, and it's also not about param1. I would like to know if there's a way to know that param2 has a default value of "A", that I can call function2 using param2 default value ("A") using some code like option 2 above. But OK, I quit, I'll do it like Option 1.

Comment: @Ricardo Yes, I understand completely. My point is that there is no purpose for such an operator.  If you know the type, you know the type, if you don't know the type, then it's default(T) and if you must ascertain the type at runtime there is reflection.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE using action delegates:

```
private void Function2(string param2 = "A")
{
    // no-op
    Console.WriteLine($"Param2 = {param2}");
}

private void Function1(string param1)
{
    var actionsDictionary = new Dictionary<bool, Action<string>>
    {
        { false, this.Function2 },
        { true, (p) => { this.Function2(); } }
    };

    actionsDictionary[string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param1)](param1);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestNow()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Begin invoking Function1 with different params");
    Function1(null);
    Function1(String.Empty);
    Function1("        ");
    Function1("Some Value");
    Console.WriteLine("End invoking Function1 with different params");
}
```

**And this is the test method output:**

> Test Name:    TestNow
>
> Test Outcome: Passed
>
> Result StandardOutput:
>
> Begin invoking Function1 with different params
>
> Param2 = A
>
> Param2 = A
>
> Param2 = A
>
> Param2 = Some Value
>
> End invoking Function1 with different params

You can scratch the below answer.

Default values will be used only if the respective data type's default value is not supplied. In your case Funciton2 takes string data type for which default value is null. So, "A" will only be used when Function2 receives null.

- If you are sure that param1 will never have empty string (like "" or "   "), then you could simply call

> ```
> Function2(param1)
> ```

- If param1 may contain empty string or spaces then in this case,
  Function2's default value will not be taken. So,

> ```
> if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param1))
> {
>     param1 = null;
> }
> Function2(param1)
> ```

Comment: In neither of these cases will the default value of `param2` (`"A"`) be used. If you specify an argument to the method, that value will be used.

Comment: Per my understanding of the question, default_param_value needs to be used instead of param2. (not worrying about what's defined in Function2 header).. Please read the question before updating

Comment: The OP states *"not worrying about what's defined in Function2 header"*, which indicates that there is no way to set `default_param_value` to the correct value. Maybe I'm misreading it? But in any case, the default value of the parameter is defined in the method: `string param2 = "A"`. It will not be used if you pass in a value.

Comment: Hopefully the OP can jump in here, because he already has sample code in `// OPTION 2` that does what this answer suggests (it's literally what you have in the second code block, only more concise), which is what's leading me to believe it's not correct. There is no way to set `default_param_value` to the correct value without "worrying about what's defined in Function2 header". If you show how you set `default_param_value` without using reflection, that would probably be the answer.

Comment: @Rufus, you are right. default_param_value does not exists, it's not a variable. I would like to know if there's something like this pseudo keyword. The first part of this answer only works if param1 is null, but if it's empty, MessageBox will show "", and I would like it to show "A".

Comment: @sam Your edit is incorrect - if you pass `null` as the argument value, then `null` will be used. If you don't specify anything, *then* the default value will be used.

Comment: @Richardo, please use second option in my answer.

Comment: Please test your answer...it does not work the way you think it does.

Comment: @Rufus L, your aboslutely right, null will be used instead of "A" in this case. The second option in this answer does not work.